# SSIS 2012 - Errored out with Merge Join Transformation

Tags: oracle, ssis-2012, attunity

I am trying to create a merge join in SSIS 2012 but i am getting below error

"**Validation error. Data Flow Task: No input columns found. At least one input column must be mapped to an output column**."

Here is what my Data Flow is

I have 1 Flat file Source and 1 Oracle (Attunity) Source, both of these sources are sorted by Sort Transformation.
then i am applying the Merge Join on these sources.

What could be the reason?

SSIS 2012 
Oracle 11g
Attunity v 2.0 driver installed.

I can't even edit the merge join transformation.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It is problem with the data conversion on a column.  I removed that particular column from merge join, then there is no error.

But later i again put back the errored column back to the Merge Join without any error.